# How can I fade a div out when a button is clicked?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```js
function animateHelloworld() {
  document.querySelector('#hello-world').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('#button').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#hello-world {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-world">
  Hello world
</div>
<div id="button">
  <button onclick="animateHelloworld()">press me</button>
</div>
```

I want the div and the button fade away as I press the button thank you.
I am a begginer thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't use a CSS transition to animate the `display` property. Related question: [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property)

Comment: Protip: Tags are text in your markup. _Elements_ are what you see in the browser. You can't click a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot animate non-numeric properties like `display`. Change the opacity instead.

```js
function animateHelloworld() {
  document.querySelector('#hello-world').style.opacity = "1";
  document.querySelector('#button').style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```css
#hello-world {
  opacity: 0;
}

#hello-world,
#button {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-world">
  Hello world
</div>
<div id="button">
  <button onclick="animateHelloworld()">press me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try this, thank you for your answer @korki :)

Comment: but I can still click the button. Do you know how to get rid of it? @korki

Comment: You can add `document.querySelector('#button').disabled = true;` to the `animateHelloworld` function, so the button gets disabled when the function is called